# How does CSS border-width trick works to create triangles in CSS?

Tags: html, css, border

I recently stumbled upon this [David Walsh's blog post](http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles) to create triangles in pure CSS. 
Here is the code for creating a triangle pointing upwards

```
div.arrow-up {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;  /* left arrow slant */
    border-right: 5px solid transparent; /* right arrow slant */
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2f2f2f; /* bottom, add background color here */
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Here is the [working Jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/puwugoja/1/edit?html,css,output).

Can somebody help me understand how is this working ?
According to me all three borders should have created borders at (left, right, bottom) So it should have been something like `|__|` shape but how am I getting the slant edges ?